# To Print Column Data in rows using SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I wrote this query--

```
select
sum(case when [Station Code] between '50000' and '50999' then 1 else 0 end) as [50000 to 50999],
SUM(case when [Station Code] between '51000' and '51999' then 1 else 0 end) as [51000 to 51999],
SUM(case when [Station Code] between '52000' and '52999' then 1 else 0 end) as [52000 to 52999],
SUM(case when [Station Code] between '53000' and '53999' then 1 else 0 end) as [53000 to 53999],
SUM(case when [Station Code] between '54000' and '54999' then 1 else 0 end) as [54000 to 54999] from dbo.Import_Data
```

**And the result is as follows:**

```
50000 to 5099 51000 to51999 52000 to52999 53000 to53999 54000 to54999

28  8  20  11  41
```

**I want the result like this:**

```
50000 to 5099  28  
51000 to51999  8  
52000 to52999  20  
53000 to53999  11  
54000 to54999  41
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use unpivot

```
select * from (
select
sum(case when [Station Code] between '50000' and '50999' then 1 else 0 end) as [50000 to 50999],
SUM(case when [Station Code] between '51000' and '51999' then 1 else 0 end) as [51000 to 51999],
SUM(case when [Station Code] between '52000' and '52999' then 1 else 0 end) as [52000 to 52999],
SUM(case when [Station Code] between '53000' and '53999' then 1 else 0 end) as [53000 to 53999],
SUM(case when [Station Code] between '54000' and '54999' then 1 else 0 end) as [54000 to 54999] from dbo.Import_Data) d
unpivot 
(
value for result in ([50000 to 50999],[51000 to 51999],[52000 to 52999],[53000 to 53999],[54000 to 54999]
) t
```